# Does the log4j2 JDBC Appender close the connection by itself?

Tags: java, jdbc, log4j2

I've been finding that the log4j2 jdbc appender is really slow every single time an error is being pushed to the database. I think the jdbc appender is closing the connection every single time and then making a new connection. If this is the case, is there some way I can have the appender stop closing the connection everytime? I have the connection stored in the database connection class that I made and I close the connection before the program terminates.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [documentation](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/appenders.html#JDBCAppender) says that the DataSource that you use for the connector should use a connection pool:

> It can be configured to obtain JDBC connections using a JNDI DataSource or a custom factory method.
>
> ...
>
> Whichever approach you take, it must be backed by a connection pool. Otherwise, logging performance will suffer greatly.

So it is up to your implementation, that you didn't share here. It is not log4j2 responsibility to implement a JDBC connection pool.

It would not be a good idea to try to implement a custom database connection pool. Use one of the existing libraries for that.

Comment: Yeah, that makes sense, I originally had a basic data source connection pool from apache commons but I got rid of it because I only really need 1 connection and I'm not doing any multi-threading nor do any other programs that I'm running need the extra connections, that's why I was hoping to be able to just use 1 connection and have log4j not close the connection since I'm doing it on my end.

Comment: @WillW. Given Log4j also needed connections, your application did in fact not _"only really need 1 connection"_. Also, for long running applications, even if they only need a single connection, it can still make sense to use a (small) connection pool: get a connection for a unit of work, and close it when the unit of work is complete. That way, connection problems can generally be easily recoverable (or maybe even invisible to your application code).

Comment: Only one connection could cause performance or concurrency problems easily. For example log4j2 may be logging in different threads. Always use a pool.